# A regex for 1000 1 000 and 1,000

Tags: regex

I am trying to come up with a regex to identify different format of numerals like `1000` `1 000` and `1,000` as well as `1000000` `1 000 000` etc.
I tried the following

```
(?<=(\s|,))\d{1,}(?=(\s|,))
```

but I need it to include the space or comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `\d+([\s,]*\d*)*`? Didn't get to test it, but I think it should work

Comment: It does. Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as Accepted :-)